# Python __iter__ and for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, iterable

As I understand it, I can use the `for` loop construction on an object with a `__iter__` method that returns an iterator.  I have an object for which I implement the following `__getattribute__` method:

```
def __getattribute__(self,name):
    if name in ["read","readlines","readline","seek","__iter__","closed","fileno","flush","mode","tell","truncate","write","writelines","xreadlines"]:
        return getattr(self.file,name)
    return object.__getattribute__(self,name)
```

I have an object of this class, `a` for which the following happens:

```
>>> hasattr(a,"__iter__")
True
>>> for l in a: print l
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'TmpFile' object is not iterable
>>> for l in a.file: print l
...
>>>
```

So python sees that `a` has an `__iter__` method, but doesn't think it is iterable.  What have I done wrong?  This is with python 2.6.4.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a subtle implementation detail getting in your way: `__iter__` isn't actually an instance method, but a class method.  That is, `obj.__class__.__iter__(obj)` is called, rather than `obj.__iter__()`.

This is due to slots optimizations under the hood, allowing the Python runtime to set up iterators faster.  This is needed since it's very important that iterators be as fast as possible.

It's not possible to define `__getattribute__` for the underlying `class` type, so it's not possible to return this method dynamically.  This applies to most `__metamethods__`; you'll need to write an actual wrapper.

Comment: +1 So that's why `iter` doesn't call `__getattribute__`... as they say, you learn something new on SO every day :)

Comment: Note that you can see a side-effect of this (at least in CPython): if you define `__getattribute__`, you'll notice it gets called for `__class__` when you use `iter`, as the runtime looks up the class of the object to call `__iter__`.  (This should probably be considered an implementation detail.)

Answer (score 4):

Some of the special methods are optimised when a class is created and cannot be added later or overridden by assignment. See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) for `__getattribute__` which says:

> This method may still be bypassed when
>   looking up special methods as the
>   result of implicit invocation via
>   language syntax or built-in functions.

What you need to do in this case is provide a direct implementation of `__iter__` that forwards the call:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return self.file.__iter__()
```