# Method overriding by monkey patching

Tags: python, inheritance, overriding

I'm trying to figure out why the following example won't work.

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 1

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.count:
            self.count -= 1
            return self
        else:
            raise StopIteration


class DerivedNO(BaseClass):
    pass


class DerivedO(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.new_count = 2
        self.next = self.new_next

    def new_next(self):
        if self.new_count:
            self.new_count -= 1
            return None
        else:
            raise StopIteration


x = DerivedNO()
y = DerivedO()

print x
print list(x)
print y
print list(y)
```

And here is the output:

```
<__main__.DerivedNO object at 0x7fb2af7d1c90>
[<__main__.DerivedNO object at 0x7fb2af7d1c90>]
<__main__.DerivedO object at 0x7fb2af7d1d10>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "playground.py", line 41, in <module>
    print list(y)
  File "playground.py", line 11, in next
    if self.count:
AttributeError: 'DerivedO' object has no attribute 'count'
```

As you can see the new method will not be overridden in `DerivedO` when I try to assign the `next()` method in `__init__`. Why is that? A simple call to next will work fine, but not at all when using iterating techniques.

Edit: I realize my question wasn't completely clear. The AttributeError isn't the problem I'm looking to solve. But it does show that `next()` is called on `BaseClass` instead of on `DerivedO` as I thought it would.

Comment: I think you just need to call the base class `__init__` in your derived class constructor.

Comment: @sje397: that's the point; the `new_next` method does not refer to `count`.

Comment: Interesting, when returning `self` from `__iter__` the class-defined `next` is used, whatever `next` may have been set to on the instance. The same applies to the `__iter__` method, patching it with a method using `yield` is also ignored.

Comment: Aha. Yeah, that's weird.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python `__iter__` and for loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300988/python-iter-and-for-loops)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot monkeypatch either `__iter__(self)` or, by extension, `next(self)` on instances because these methods are treated as class methods instead as a CPython internal optimization (see [Special method lookup for new-style classes](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup-for-new-style-classes) for an in-depth rationale as to why this is).

If you need to monkeypatch these methods, you'll need to set them *directly* on the class instead:

```
class DerivedO(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.new_count = 2
        self.__class__.next = self.__class__.new_next

    def new_next(self):
        if self.new_count:
            self.new_count -= 1
            return None
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

The above will work; note that I set `__class__.next` to the *unbound* function `new_next`, not to the bound method.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you. Everytime I think I know Python it always turns out there's a lot more to it!

Comment: This will work, but it's worth mentioning that at this point, you might as well just override the method using standard syntax (i.e. by putting `next = new_next` after the definition of `new_next`). The approach you use here is rather obfuscated!

Comment: @senderle: I was assuming the OP had constructed an example to illustrate his problem. The monkeypatching could also happen on classes outside of his or her control, at which point the theory behind my answer still applies.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, OK, I see what you mean. I just thought it was worth mentioning as a caveat.

Comment: Yeah, the idea was to select a lean next function during init depending on certain runtime information instead of having to go through a lot of ifs and elifs each iteration. But it's getting overly complex so I think I'll go for another approach instead. Mainly I was annoyed it didn't work the way I thought it should.

Answer (score -1):

Since `DerivedO` never initializes the `count` attribute, an AttributeError occurs when the `next` method is executed.

You could avoid this error by arranging for `BaseClass.__init__` to be called (either explicitly, or by using `super`):

```
class DerivedO(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DerivedO, self).__init__()
        self.new_count = 2

    def next(self):
        if self.new_count:
            self.new_count -= 1
            return None
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

Also, instead of defining `new_next`, you could simply override (redefine) `next`.

Comment: That's it though; the OP has an interesting question. Why can't you *monkeypatch* next? The iterator uses the class-defined `next` method, not the instance override. You are not addressing the real issue here.